# XP, permissions messed up, can I copy files and folders, format and copy back?

Tags: windows-xp, permissions

I've been having problems with permissions on my D: drive, so not my system volume. I was thinking I could copy the contents of my D: partition onto my external drive, format D: and copy the files back.

However, I'm just wondering if the permissions / ownership will remain on the files and folders ?

Comment: Thinking the best option would be to set the permissions correctly (i.e. so they work for you) - not that that is necessarily easy.  Don't recall exactly, but in the same situation I may have added an EVERYONE user, giving Full control.  It met my needs but is not likely an optimal method.

Comment: True but I want to resize my partition and do a backup anyway. So makes sence to do all at once if poss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permissions / Ownership will remain between NTFS-formatted volumes by design. If you are moving to a FAT32 volume, Permissions / Ownership will be stripped from the files.

Are you able to right-click on files or folders and change the ownership and permissions?

If you need to know how, ask.

Comment: So if I make my external drive fat32 then copy back permissions will be lost?

Comment: Thanks.  Hadn't really considered that before.  Note that some file manager or copy utilities may offer options in regard to ownership & permissions.

Comment: If you just copy the files using explorer, the permissions will be lost moving to a FAT32 volume as the file system does not support those attributes. What utilities say they can do this? I am curious as to how that's handled by said utilities.